# Array Division Issue With PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have a very small problem but I am just unable to fix this.

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Asset Address 1 Label] => 
            [Asset Address 1 Organization] => 
            [Asset Address 1 Name prefix] => Hotel Taj
            [Asset Address 1 First name] => Maan
            [Asset Address 1 Middle name] => Singh
            [Asset Address 1 Last name] => Hotel
            [Asset Address 1 Name suffix] => 
            [Asset Address 1 Street] => 
            [Asset Address 1 Street 2] => 
            [Asset Address 1 Zip/Postal Code] => 110020
            [Asset Address 1 City] => 
            [Asset Address 1 State] => 
            [Asset Address 1 State Combined code] => IN-DL
            [Asset Address 1 Country ISO2 code] => IN
            [Asset Address 1 Types 1 Name] => billing
            [Asset Address 1 Types 2 Name] => 
            [Asset Address 2 Label] => Himachal
            [Asset Address 2 Organization] => 
            [Asset Address 2 Name prefix] => 
            [Asset Address 2 First name] => Hotel
            [Asset Address 2 Middle name] => 
            [Asset Address 2 Last name] => Taj
            [Asset Address 2 Name suffix] => 
            [Asset Address 2 Street] => 
            [Asset Address 2 Street 2] => 
            [Asset Address 2 Zip/Postal Code] => 110020
            [Asset Address 2 City] => 
            [Asset Address 2 State] => 
            [Asset Address 2 State Combined code] => IN-CT
            [Asset Address 2 Country ISO2 code] => IN
            [Asset Address 2 Types 1 Name] => shipping
            [Asset Address 2 Types 2 Name] => 
        )

)
```

I am trying to break the internal Asset Address 1 & 2 into another dimension within the array

```
    Array
    (

    [0] => Array
        (
        [0] => Array
            (
            [Asset Address 1 Label] => asas
            [Asset Address 1 Organization] => 
            [Asset Address 1 Name prefix] => 
            [Asset Address 1 First name] => asas
            [Asset Address 1 Middle name] => asasas
            [Asset Address 1 Last name] => asasa
            [Asset Address 1 Name suffix] => asasa
            [Asset Address 1 Street] => asasa
            [Asset Address 1 Street 2] => 
            [Asset Address 1 Zip/Postal Code] => 121212
            [Asset Address 1 City] => 
            [Asset Address 1 State] => 
            [Asset Address 1 State Combined code] => AO-CUS
            [Asset Address 1 Country ISO2 code] => AO
            [Asset Address 1 Types 1 Name] => billing
            [Asset Address 1 Types 2 Name] => shipping
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
            [Asset Address 2 Label] => 
            [Asset Address 2 Organization] => 
            [Asset Address 2 Name prefix] => 
            [Asset Address 2 First name] => 
            [Asset Address 2 Middle name] => 
            [Asset Address 2 Last name] => 
            [Asset Address 2 Name suffix] => 
            [Asset Address 2 Street] => 
            [Asset Address 2 Street 2] => 
            [Asset Address 2 Zip/Postal Code] => 
            [Asset Address 2 City] => 
            [Asset Address 2 State] => 
            [Asset Address 2 State Combined code] => 
            [Asset Address 2 Country ISO2 code] => 
            [Asset Address 2 Types 1 Name] => 
            [Asset Address 2 Types 2 Name] =>
            )

        )

    )
```

Please note since there are other field in the array not displayed above and therefore I had to try filtering using regular expression as follows:

```
        $filtred = array();
        foreach($csv as $oldkey => $value){
            $regExpression = '/(Asset Address )['.$oldkey.'] [\w]+/';
            foreach ($value as $key => $value) {
                if(preg_match($regExpression , $key)){
                    $filtred[$oldkey][$key] = $value;
                }
            }
        }
        print_r($filtred);
```

**The problem:**

This is not working from the beginning of the array basically when `$oldkey` is 0 it skips and works for `$oldkey1`. Why?

Also, with this method I am creating a seperate array altogether, I'm trying to have that as in extra dimension within the existing array.

I hope I've explained well.

Comment: when the `$oldkey` is `0`, the regexp will be `/(Asset Address )[0] [\w]+/`. Is there any array key with `0`?

Comment: Oh how silly, ok i added $oldkey + 1 and it has started accepting both Asset Address 1 & 2. Thanks!

Comment: @Deadooshka Problem 1 solved, any ideas on how I can replace the existing address fields into a multidimensional array within the same array?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code for formating as you mentioned above.

```
$filtred = array();
$n = 1;
foreach($csv as $oldkey => $values){
    $i = 0; $j = 0;
    foreach (array_keys($values) as $key => $value) {
        if(!preg_match('/(Asset Address )['.$n.'] [\w]+/' , $value)){
            $n++; $j++;
        }
        $filtred[$i][$j][$value] = $values[$value];
    }
    $i++;
}
```